# action performed only once

Tags: java, swing

I've got a form with `gridLayout` which contains 15 `JButtons` and one `JLabel`. Every button has an action and when it's fired It should show `clicked!`, perform some operation and show in console its position.

But it shows position in console only once - when I press any button first time. After that only `clicked` text appears in console.

What's the problem?

```
public class PuzzleUI extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int gap = 2;

private Puzzle puzzle;
private JComponent[][] itemGrid;
private JPanel controls;

public PuzzleUI(String title, int puzzles, int empty_cell) {
    super(title);
    puzzle = new Puzzle(puzzles, empty_cell);
    itemGrid = new JComponent[puzzle.getRowSize()][puzzle.getRowSize()];
    controls = new JPanel();
    controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(puzzle.getRowSize(), puzzle
            .getRowSize(), gap, gap));
    init(this.getContentPane());
}

public void init(final Container pane) {

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object ob = e.getSource();
            boolean finished = false;
            if (ob instanceof JButton) {
                System.out.println("Clicked!");
                int cnt = 0;
                label: for (int i = 0; i < itemGrid.length; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < itemGrid[i].length; j++) {
                        if (itemGrid[i][j] == (JButton) ob) {
                            System.out.println(i + "-" + j); // appeared only once
                            finished = puzzle.swap(cnt);
                            break label;
                        }
                        cnt++;
                    }
                PuzzleUI.this.init(PuzzleUI.this.getContentPane());
                PuzzleUI.this.controls.repaint();
                if (finished == true)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            PuzzleUI.this,
                            "FINISHED WITH MOVE: "
                                    + PuzzleUI.this.puzzle.getMoves());
            }
        }
    };

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemGrid.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < itemGrid[i].length; j++) {
            int value = puzzle.getListItem(cnt);
            if (value == puzzle.getEmptyFlag())
                itemGrid[i][j] = new JLabel("");
            else {
                JButton jb = new JButton(String.valueOf(value));
                jb.addActionListener(al);
                itemGrid[i][j] = jb;
            }
            controls.add(itemGrid[i][j]);
            cnt++;
        }
    pane.add(controls);
}
}
```

Comment: When a button is clicked, you call init() again, and thus reinitialize the whole GUI. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @JB Nizet Hm...But how to reload buttons again (when I click I want to change button's position)

Comment: I don't have any idea of what you're trying to achieve, but simply changing the text of the existing buttons should be enough.

Comment: @JB Nizet I'm making 15 puzzle when with elements - buttons.

Comment: I've found a solution. I'll create button instead of JLabel